# How do I setup a service to receive some options in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm just getting my head round setting up my own services to inject from `Startup.cs` in an ASP.NET Core 3.1+ project.

So far I created an interface and a class:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

I added the service in startup using:

```
services.AddScoped<Services.IMyClass, Services.MyClass>();
```

Which works fine, except I want this class to have various strings it can return based on the current configuration and I have no idea how to pass those variables from `appsettings.json` to populate `SomeString` so I can then `get` it from in a controller.

I was trying this:

```
services.AddScoped<Services.IMyClass, Services.MyClass>(
    Configuration.GetValue<string>("SomeAppSettingKey");
```

To pull a string from appsettings, but don't know how to populate a constructor in the class with the string. Do I need to add some sort of `options` class as a property in `MyClass` ?

---

There's lots of hints on how I can be adding some of these config settings but I'm just missing some info e.g.

```
        services.AddTransient<IMyClass, MyClass>();
        services.Configure<MyClass>(Configuration);
```

Makes syntactical sense to me but I'm still not sure how to populate the string in `MyClass` by passing the `Configuration` here.

Comment: Why did you just delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533575/how-do-i-return-a-new-instance-of-a-taskresponse ? It was a good question. You also shouldn't return `null`.

Comment: I just undeleted it - I tried returning null but it didn't work :D

Comment: Lol it was such a good question it got closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a model to store the setting extracted from configuration

```
public class MyClassOptions {
    public string SomeAppSettingKey { get; set; }
}
```

*(Note the matching names)*

Configure it at Startup

```
services.Configure<MyClassOptions>(Configuration);
```

*(This assumes the key is in the root of the settings file)*

Update the target class to inject the options configured

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass {

    public MyClass (IOptions<MyClassOptions> options) {
        SomeString = options.Value.SomeAppSettingKey;
    }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

Reference [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options)

Comment: Thanks so much, I was looking at the provided link but was getting confused. I had just created an options class but now I know to stick that in as a constructor parameter as well.